# Django web application handling post requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django and am confused on handling post requests to my server. I want to accept post requests in this json format: `{“username”:”john@doe.com”,”password”:”pass@word1”}` and to reply with these json formated responses:

`{“status”:”success”,”message”:”user_authed”}` if the user and password combination is found
`{“status”:”failure”,”message”:”user_not_found”}` if the user and password combination is not found

This is my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from . models import users
from . serializers import userSerializer


class userList(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    user = users.objects.all()
    serializer = userSerializer(user, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = userSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to know how I can format the post function to accept requests in the format above and how to customize the reply as authenticated or not. Any help would be appreciated with this

Comment: you can customize response using serialize, please include your serializers code in this question

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is called authentication. 
Please read https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ in advance.

Then edit your question according to what you learn.

Hope to hear from you soon!

```
#serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
UserRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer)
    username = CharField(required=True, max_length=128)
    password = CharField(required=True, max_length=128)

#views.py
from .serializers import *

UserCheckView(APIView):

    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserRequestSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=serializer.validated_data['username'])
            if user.check_password(serializer.validated_data['password']:
                return Response(data={“status”:”success”,”message”:”user_authed”},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(data={“status”:”failure”,”message”:”password_did_not_match”}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(data={“status”:”failure”,”message”:”user_not_found”}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: Hi engin_ipek. I have read the authentication link. However, it is not exactly what I am looking for. 

I don't need to create any user tokens or anything like that. I just need a basic post request in the format of my post to respond with a success or failure message. That is what I am stuck with right now.

Thanks

Comment: hi there i really cant imagine why you need this but i have updated my answer :)

Comment: Hi engin, there is a key error with the line: user = User.objects.get(username=serializer.validated_data['username'] on 'username'. 

Also would it not be users instead of User?

Thanks for your help so far, much appreciated

Comment: can you share your user model as well in your question?